# How to execute a long running operation?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any resources I can go to for tips on how to make a winForm with a long running operation?

My scenario is this.  I have a WinForm that calls an API and stores data into a datagridview with multiple columns and about 10,000+ Rows.

I'm running multiple operations, such as counting distinct instances of a value in different columns and running a math operator to get a value. That application runs on about 2000 rows, but when I get to 4000, I get COM errors or other things stop it from executing.

I don't care if I have access to the UI, I just need the application to run.

Comment: Please provide some source code so that might answer can exemplify this for you

Comment: You need to run the operations in the background using threads or other processes - most common way of doing this is with threading, but there's more than one way to do this.  You probably want to start with something like this [Threading Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx) or anyone of a number of similar articles.

Comment: Please write more concrete about COM errors (exception info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any resources I can go to for tips on how to make a winForm with a long running operation?

Sure, there are lots of resources for this sort of thing. You are more than likely looking for the [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a great "code project" on it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += OnDoWork;
    }

    void OnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Long running code here.
    }
}
```

The `BackgroundWorker` supports cancellation, and even reporting of progress. Additionally, there are several other key events you would want to implement.

Ideally, you will clean up and dispose of the object when your form is done using it - additionally, be sure to unwire event handlers as part of the cleanup. Here is another [resource](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker).

Comment: I use alot of the UI objects directly in the method. Is this bad practice? For example if I have a listbox1 that has a value which is set before running the operation, I call it in the method using listbox1.text. I know there are way to call the UI object so it doesn't give me an error, but is it better to store all the object values into a variables?

Comment: You just have to ensure that when you're interacting with the UI that you marshal the operations back to the UI thread, this can be done via `Invoke/BeginInvoke`. I wrote an extension method for this years ago. https://onlycsharp.wordpress.com/sharpening/extension-methods/

Comment: Why advice using a backgroundworker when the msdn states that using tpl is the way to go? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx. Also, see this post of Stephen Cleary about how to replace the backgroundworker with async/await. No need to Invoke/BeginInvoke and such.

Comment: Stephen Cleary provides a comparison of the two, not a replace all. I have the async work starting in the constructor. TPL is still a very valid option here, I posted this based on what I felt was right with the limited amount of info from the OP.